# Resize xfs root partition

Tags: linux, fedora, partition, xfs

Fedora 25

Hey guys,

I've just cloned my 120gb SSD to a 240gb SSD, and would like to extend my root partition.

It seems this isn't as easy as I was hoping and could use some assistance!

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd09196e4

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   2099199   2097152    1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200  18636799  16537600  7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        18636800 123494399 104857600   50G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       123494400 250068991 126574592 60.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       123496448 250068991 126572544 60.4G 83 Linux
```

(parted) print

```
Model: ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      1075MB  9542MB  8467MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
 3      9542MB  63.2GB  53.7GB  primary   xfs
 4      63.2GB  128GB   64.8GB  extended
 5      63.2GB  128GB   64.8GB  logical   xfs
```

df -h

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        12G   16K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       7.9G  1.1M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                       7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3                    50G   12G   39G  24% /
/dev/sda1                   976M   85M  825M  10% /boot
/dev/sda5                    61G  408M   60G   1% /home
```

I've tried xfs_growfs but nothing changes, gparted (live usb boot) doesn't allow me to change the size. I know I have 4 active partitions, but unsure how to get past this limitation (is it a limitation?)

I tried following https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition with no success as well.

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I can't see it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the obvious fact that Fedora 25 is [EOL](https://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-25-end-life/).

It looks like you cannot grow `sda3` because there's no free space contiguous to that partition (marks are mine):

```
/dev/sda3        18636800 *123494399* 104857600   50G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       *123494400* 250068991 126574592 60.4G  5 Extended
```

It also looks like you are not using `sda4` for anything at all (from the output of `df`). If this is the case (and note that if you actually use it but it wasn't mounted when you run `df` I can't know it), you can:

1. take a complete backup of the system
2. delete `sda4`
3. after that, you can delete the sda3 partition. This step sounds scary, but you are only deleting the partition definition
4. re-create `sda3` using its original start (18636800) and use `sda4`'s end (250068991)
5. save the changes
6. grow the filesystem

That said, depending on the complexity of the installation with regards to installed software, and assuming this is a desktop installation, I would instead recommend the following actions to avoid further problems down the line:

1. generate a manifest of the packages currently installed for future reference
2. generate a backup of your `/home` partition and/or interesting or customised configuration files (configuration management systems can help reproduce custom setups)
3. install a fresh Fedora 29, there are too many bugfixes and improvements to ignore compared to a very old and EOLed Fedora 25
4. when installing, partition your new disk using [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)
5. take advantage of LVM2 for the rest of the disk, you can keep `/boot` in a separate partition. Using logical volumes completely avoids the problem you are having now.
6. check the list of packages from #1 and reinstall anything you need (using current versions)
7. restore your `/home` (pay attention to permissions and SELinux labels when doing so)
8. test the system

It's worth the effort.